# Watson Discovery Service

Tags: watson-discovery

We are trying to design a Knowledge Search box , using Watson Discovery Service . Planning to use Data Crawler to read real-time data from our Knowledge repository.  We are looking for some information on how the responses of Discovery services can be ranked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, you can't affect the ranking of Discovery service results. That feature is on the roadmap, but AFAIK, there's been no announcement date.

Answer (score 0):

Discovery will rank the documents based on relevancy that they have regarding your query. You can use filters with the metadata created to improve the relevancy. 
In the latest version of the API relevancy training is an option. With this training you can improve the search results by training the systems with examples based on queries. This will provide a significant uplift in the results.